# How to hide those two <span> elements specifically for each input in jquery or javascript? Seeking a generic solution

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am doing this for validating multiple input fields with different data intake using a generic function to which I can pass RegExp output and display the validation message or icon.

This is my HTML code

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="fname" class="form-lable">First name</label>
   <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" class="form-input" required>
   <div for="fname">
       <span class="validation-container success"><i class="bi bi-check2"></i></span>
       <span class="validation-container error"><i class="bi bi-x"></i></span>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="lname" class="form-lable">First name</label>
   <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" class="form-input" required>
   <div for="lname">
       <span class="validation-container success"><i class="bi bi-check2"></i></span>
       <span class="validation-container error"><i class="bi bi-x"></i></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is what I am doing

```
$('#fname').on('keyup', function () {
    $('.validation-container').hide();
});
$('#lname').on('keyup', function () {
    $('.validation-container').hide();
});
```

What it does:

```
It's doing that thing for both of the inputs.
```

```
$('#fname').on('keyup', function () { 
    $(this).parent().find('.validation-container').hide(); 
    let check = fnameRegExp.test($(this).val()); 
    let success = ".validation-container.success"; 
    let wrong = ".validation-container.error"; 
    validateInput(check, success, wrong); 
});
```

What I am doing here is sending regex match, success as well as wrong classes to the function. If the input is not matched with the regex then it will display the div having that wrong class.

```
function validateInput(check, success, wrong) {
    if (check) {
        $(success).show();
        checkAll();
    } else {
        $(wrong).show();
    }
}
```

And I am calling that function on keyup for each input. what it does is, it shows validation signs (✅, ❎) for every input.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
<div for="fname" id="fnameValidators">
       <span class="validation-container success"><i class="bi bi-check2"></i></span>
       <span class="validation-container error"><i class="bi bi-x"></i></span>
</div>

$('#fname').on('keyup', function () {
    $('#fnameValidators').hide();
});
```

Similarly make changes for last name.

Comment: `$('#fname').on('keyup', function () { $(this).parent().find('.validation-container').hide(); let check = fnameRegExp.test($(this).val()); let success = ".validation-container.success"; let wrong = ".validation-container.error"; validateInput(check, success, wrong); });` What I am doing here is sending regex match, success as well as wrong classes to the function. If the input is not matched with the regex then it will display the div having that wrong class. `function validateInput(check, success, wrong) {if (check) {$(success).show();checkAll();} else {$(wrong).show();}}`

Comment: And I am calling that function on keyup for each input. what it does is, it shows validation signs (✅, ❎) for every input.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

Use

```
$(this).parent().find('.validation-container').hide();
```

To hide only the element with that class within the same container.

### Longer version

`$('.validation-container')` searches in the whole DOM. To restrict it, you can use this selector within another element. Since you're reading the `keyup` event on the `input`, you can simply use `$(this)` to obtain the input object. Then go over 1 level with `.parent()` to select the `<div class="form-group">` containing it and finally use `find('.validation-container')` to select the correct `span` you want to hide.

As one-liner:

```
$(this).parent().find('.validation-container').hide();
```

### Even more dynamic

If you want to make this even more dynamic, you can avoid calling a `keyup` event for each separate input, and create a single function that manages all your inputs correctly.

```
$('.form-lable').on('keyup', function () {
    var type = $(this).attr('id')
    // You can use the variable type to distinguish between the two inputs
    $(this).parent().find('.validation-container').hide();
});
```

Comment: `$('#fname').on('keyup', function () {
$(this).parent().find('.validation-container').hide();
let check = fnameRegExp.test($(this).val());
let success = ".validation-container.success";
let wrong = ".validation-container.error";
validateInput(check, success, wrong);
}); ` What I am doing here is sending regex match,  success as well as wrong classes to the function. If the input is not matched with the regex then it will display the div having that wrong class. `function validateInput(check, success, wrong) {if (check) {$(success).show();checkAll();} else {$(wrong).show();}}`

Comment: And I am calling that function on keyup for each input. what it does is, it shows validation signs (✅, ❎) for every input.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
$('#fname').on('keyup', function () {
    $("div[for='fname']").find('.validation-container').hide();
});
$('#lname').on('keyup', function () {
    $("div[for='lname']").find('.validation-container').hide();
});
```